# trying to produce a string in C# containing "@" character

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out how to specify a literal string in C# that contains an "@" at symbol followed by a space (asp.net mvc 5 actually). Searching the internet has proved fruitless in this effort. Seems the search engines are smarter than I and already know I couldn't possibly be searching for what I asked for. Any help how to construct such an evil string? thanks.

Comment: `string x = "@ ";` But to be honest I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *"a literal string in C# that contains an "@" at symbol followed by a space"*, because surely it's not as obvious as this. Do you mean a *verbatim* string literal? But if so, then it's just `string x = @"@ ";`

Comment: I suspect that if your @ is disappearing, then something else is swallowing it.  It does not have anything to do with the C# language.  You need to follow the trail carefully step by step to see what's happening with your string. If you write a simple C# console app with Console.WriteLine, you will quickly see that there is no issue with an @ in a string.  You may want to provide more details and show more code.  @ is not a special character in strings in C#

Comment: Yes, "@ ". And you would think it would be that easy. or even "\@ ". These both (as well as @"@ "), throw a compiler error: Quote: A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character. Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following "@" with no space in between. EndQuote.

Comment: ...And before someone else suggests I use "@@ ", I tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
    string atSymbol = "\u0040";